# MYSQL Views and lookups

Tags: mysql, database, sql-view

I need a little input on using views. So I have a view with some values. Now in that view I want to do the following:

Grab a value from a MYSQL table and do a look up for that value from another table(this table has ranges), the tables are all in the same databases.

So for example, I am using value 10 from table 1. Now I want to look up that value in table 2 and extract the other columns from it,so the final columns(output) I'll get in my view are

```
10 | Bad Grade | PASS
```

Table 2 Example (3 columns)

```
1-6   | Good Grade | PASS
7-11  | Bad Grade  | PASS
12-16 | Fail       | DIDNT PASS
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select students.*
from students
join(gradeComments) on(students.grade>=gradeComments.minGrade and students.grade<=gradeComments.maxGrade)
```

(Yes, I'm a rebel who doesn't like MySQL queries in capitals.)

Also, you need to put your minimum and maximum values in table 2 in two separate columns. Instead of a column that says "7-11", you need a minimum column that says "7" and a maximum column that says "11".

The above should show every line in the "students" (Table1) table, and link it with the appropriate "gradeComment" (Table2) line. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. But, I don't want to put "10" in the query. Since I will have more grades e.g 10, 7, 4, 3 and so on. Is there any way to accomplish that? Also, I'm looking for an equals to or greater than statement instead of =. since one table has the ranges and the other has the grades.

Comment: See my edited reply. I think I had misunderstood. This should be better.